# how to make query with two operators on one condition in fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

HI i got a problem with FQL statments,
I dont understand how i can make two operators on one condition?.
This is my example code:

```
FacebookDesktop.fqlQuery("SELECT username, age, , FROM somewhere WHERE source_id = me() AND (34 > age > 20 )  LIMIT 50",httpservice1_resultHandler);
```

I dont know how to limit the age with two conditions. I tried to use many variations but it doesnt work.
Can anyone please let my know what is the correct way to do it?.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `"SELECT username, age FROM somewhere WHERE source_id = me() AND age > 20 AND  age < 34 LIMIT 50"`? Can you supply the exact query you're trying to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand what you are trying to get with that query..

Make sure that you are referring exact column name and table names while writing fql query..

Anyway try this..

```
FacebookDesktop.fqlQuery(
"SELECT username, age FROM somewhere WHERE source_id = me() 
AND age<34 AND age > 20 )  LIMIT 50"
,httpservice1_resultHandler);
```

Comment: it is just an example query, not expecting to get anything of it [= i just wanted to know how to deal with the age condition. btw there is one "(" missing in the code you wrote \: it doesnt work for me